# How to Query One Firestore Collection for Values Contained within another Firestore Collection Document

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a TableView that is pulling data from the following Collection > Documents:
[image]

On my Home Screen, I want to give the user the option to show the mealPlans they have added to their *favourites.* My userFavourites collection contains a document for each user and their favourites.
[image]

How can I query Firestore to only return documents in the mealPlans collection that are contained within the `favourites` array of the document specific to the current user in the userFavourites collection? Is this something that can be accomplished in the `whereField()` method?

I think my question boils down to the following concept: how do I filter an array by another array? I.e., only include values from Array 1 that are also in Array 2.

Comment: You can fire one query to fetch data from your mealPlan collection. Once you have info from your userFavourite collection...get documents from mealPlan and plot your UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by getting the list of favorites from the `userFavourites` collection and then iterate that array and get each individual mealPlan by id, here is an example that you could apply to your case:

```
let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
var mealPlans: [DocumentSnapshot] = []
db.collection("userFavourites").doc(currentUserId).getDocument { (document, error) in
    let Favourites = document.get("favourites")
    Favourites.forEach { mealPlanId in
        db.collection("mealPlans").doc(mealPlanId).getDocument { (doc, error) in
            mealPlans.append(doc)
        }
    }
}
```